# Database designing problem with topic course section and video content

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

Currently I am trying to design a relational database that includes TOPIC, COURSE, SECTION & VIDEO_CONTENT. In my er diagram there are relations like one TOPIC can have multiple COURSE, one COURSE have multiple SECTION, one SECTION have multiple VIDEO_CONTENT. Now when a User(INSTRUCTOR) want to add COURSE he/she first choose topic then add course details like he/she create course ex- course name: OOP programming with java. now he add various section like section name: introduction to java which have 5-6 VIDEO_CONTENT then add another section name: introduction to oop programming which have 7-8 VIDEO_CONTENT etc here below is my er diagram

[image]

above this diagram is it possible to fetch how many SECTION a course have and each SECTION how many video's are there and the video duration of each section.

If i did anything wrong with my er diagram then please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Database designing problem with ..." And you do show a ER diagram, so what exactly is the problem? Do you expect the reader on SO to, try and build this, to see if you made an error in creating this diagram? How can anyone tell if this is correct, because you did not post the full (detailed) description of the intentions you had when creating this diagram.

Comment: yes i want to know is this is correct design and full fill my criteria then its ok if not then please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Assume i am only creating topics and courses after adding those 2 i want to fetch how many SECTION a course have and each SECTION how many video's are there and the video duration of each section. that's all nothing more than that

Comment: I suggest you start creating some topics and courses, and test to see if your question can be answered. (Because maybe it can, but I am not knowing the level your SQL skills....)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will start creating and testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General point: if you show an ER diagram with relationship lines going behind entities it makes it really difficult to work out if there is a relationship to that object or if the relationship is to another object

Some thoughts:

1. Why have you split TOPIC and TOPIC_DESCRIPTION? Surely that's a 1:1 relationship and so should be in a single table?
2. Similarly, why have you split COURSE and COURSE_DESCRIPTION?
3. Can a section really be related to multiple courses? If not, then use a simple FK relationship, not an intersection table
4. Can a course really be related to multiple topics? If not, then use a simple FK relationship, not an intersection table
5. Can a video content really be related to multiple sections? If not, then use a simple FK relationship, not an intersection table